# Local unitary transformation of pure two-qubits system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, unitarity

In the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.1780.pdf, at the beginning of P.2, the author is saying that:

For any states of pure two-qubit systems,

$\left| \psi \right\rangle = \alpha_{00} \left| 00 \right\rangle + \alpha_{01} \left| 01 \right\rangle + \alpha_{10} \left| 10 \right\rangle + \alpha_{11} \left| 11 \right\rangle$,

by using local unitary transformation $U = U_{A} \otimes U_{B}$, $ \left| \psi \right\rangle$ can always be converted into a state of the form $\left| \phi \right\rangle = \alpha_{00} \left| 00 \right\rangle + \alpha_{11} \left| 11 \right\rangle $ which is the Schmidt decomposition of the state $\left| \phi \right\rangle$.

How can we show that it is indeed the case ? The author is not giving any reference for this, maybe is it something trivial ?

Comment: Just using the singular value decomposition of the 2x2 matrix $M=[a00, a01; a10 a11]$, you will get $M=U \Delta V$ with U, V are unitary matrix and $\Delta$ is a diagonal matrix. Then you see how local unitary operations can achieve the goal.

Comment: @X.Dong But why does the two elements left of the basis are unchanged ? Because when i do a singular value decomposition the elements of the basis are changing.

Comment: I think you (or the paper) made a mistake there. Definitely it should not be $\alpha_{00}, \alpha_{11}$ but the singular values of the matrix M.

Comment: @X.Dong Then is it just applying the Schmidt decomposition ? In that case why is it guaranteed that I can write $\left| \phi \right\rangle$ in terms of $\left| 00 \right\rangle$ and $\left| 11 \right\rangle$ even with different coefficients ? When you look at a proof of the Schmidt decomposition, the basis is changing so I'm a bit confused...

Comment: @X.Dong Also the Schmidt decomposition, as I understand it, is just a way to re express the state in a different basis. But in my question, the state is changing and it's not just a change of basis.

Comment: Local unitary operations DO change the state. The SVD shows how you can change the state so that it will be given in a form of $\psi=a|00>+b|11>$. The local unitary operations to achieve this goal is given by the U,V from the SVD.

Comment: @X.Dong Ok I think I see now if it just applying the SVD to the matrix of the coefficients. Thank you for the help !